# Make AJAX calls securely (If possible)

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, sharepoint

I have an application with a "like" feature. I want people to be able to like an item without postbacks.

The application has an identity manager (SharePoint), so I can associate a 'like' with the user who liked it and avoid duplicates.

The question is, what would stop someone from writing a script which overrides the identity and likes an item into mega stardom?

Is there a way to make the like call with AJAX, but have all the information processed on the server side to avoid security breaches?

Comment: You haven't given enough info. How are you currently planning to implement a like?

Comment: Don't pass the identity to the server explicitly via the ajax call, rather rely on standard authentication and you can ensure on your backend that each user can only vote once for each item.

Comment: I'm currently using SPServices JQ to get the email address of the user on the page.

Comment: Since I cannot modify the standard Lists.asmx, and I'm not even sure that the service can access the user session, how would I populate identity on the back end?